# AJAX - Django - better approach?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am pretty sure, i am messing up this.

I do ajax request to get some informations of an object.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/get_obj_ajax/",
    type: "get",
    data: {id:id}
}).done(function(data){
    if(data!='bad'){
      data = data.split('°');
      var objtitle = data[0];
      var objcontent = data[1];
      ..
});
```

and in django views:

```
def get_obj_ajax(request):
   if request.method == "GET":
     obj= MyModel.objects.get(id=int(request.GET.get('id')))  
     data = obj.title + '°' + obj.content 
     return HttpResponse(data)
   return HttpResponse('bad')
```

this is what I normally do. but today while I was eating my lunch, I thought, there must be some more professional approach for this.. because i feel like this is too dumb code. and if suddenly `content` of my obj has something with `°` in it, the parsing goes wrong.

.. any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: so whats look like your obj ? can u show an example ?

Comment: @Kasra obj ist just a simple object. e.g a book with title and content. nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return `json data`:

```
def get_obj_ajax(request):
   import json
   data={"issuccess": 'no'}
   if request.method == "GET":
     obj= MyModel.objects.get(id=int(request.GET.get('id')))  
     data = {"issuccess": 'yes',"title":obj.title ,"content": obj.content}
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

in templates:

```
if(data.issuccess == 'yes'){

  var objtitle = data.title;
  var objcontent = data.content;
}...
```

Comment: @doniyor glad to help. i hope you need not to convert to `int`, ie `Mymodel.objects.get(id=request.GET['id'])` is fine. also better to check for the key `id` ie: `if request.method == 'GET' and 'id' in request.GET:`